# On windows 7 (at least) screen sharing from skype is distorted

Tags: windows, skype, screen-sharing, distortion

Whenever I get screen sharing from my clients I see their screen distorted. Like is split in 8-10 fragments each showing a different part of the screen.

When I share my screen everything is ok for them. I've checked skype forum and they are saying that me and the client have different versions and me or he should update to the same vs. But still the same issue.

How to fix the distorted screen sharing in skype?

Comment: Are both of you using the current supported version of Skype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that nvidia driver is causing this issue. (I have nvidia video card).

Just open nvidia settings and under
3D settings / Adjust image settings with preview /

Set to "Let the 3D application decide" option

PS: don't know what screen sharing had to do with 3D settings, but this fixed it for me

That should fix the issue :)